# Litecoin mining efficiency with pci-e 8x/16x

Tags: litecoin, mining-hardware

Is it essential to select a motherboard with native 2x pci-e 16x support or will 2x pci-e 8x do the same job?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Litecoin mining be bottle-necked by motherboard/cpu?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/18712/can-litecoin-mining-be-bottle-necked-by-motherboard-cpu)